# Select all but last list-element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a list of `tags` I want to display horizontally. Now for each `<li>`, but the last one, I want to add a `,` after the item.

Now, I can do that of course:

```
ul.tags {
    list-style: none;
}

ul.tags > li {
    display: inline;
}

ul.tags > li:after {
    content: ", ";
}

ul.tags > li:last-of-type:after {
    content: "";
}
```

Now I thought about combining the last two rules, like:

```
ul.tags > li:not(ul.tags > li:last-of-type):after {
    content: ", ";
}
```

But this does not work. How can I select all **but the last** `<li>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that you need is just the `:last-of-type` within the `:not` (like in the below snippet). The [`:not` accepts only simple selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot) as argument.

Below is what the [specifications](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#simple-selectors-dfn) say about simple selectors:

> A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

```css
ul.tags > li:not(:last-of-type):after {
  content: ", ";
}
ul.tags {
  list-style: none;
}
ul.tags > li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul class='tags'>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```